# How to use `where in` with slice of ints

Tags: mysql, go, slice, go-gorm

From http://jinzhu.me/gorm/advanced.html#sql-builder, I should be able to update multiple rows using WHERE IN with a single `(?)` and passing a slice to the single `?` as opposed to `WHERE IN (?,?,?,?)`.

Example from jinzhu.me as follows: `db.Exec("UPDATE orders SET shipped_at=? WHERE id IN (?)", time.Now, []int64{11,22,33})`. Here is an example of gorm's tests showing it working. https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/021d7b33143de37b743d1cf660974e9c8d3f80ea/main_test.go#L449

This doesnt work for me however:

```
var availableIds []int
for _, p := range v.Products {
    availableIds = append(availableIds, p.Id)
}

log.Println(availableIds)

db.Exec("UPDATE product_supplier SET deleted_at=? WHERE supplier_id = ? AND sku NOT IN (?)", time.Now(), 3, availableIds)
```

Output:

```
2016/04/19 07:48:44 [336 338 337 306 329 94 79 43 57 313 108 122 126 127 124 125 123 221 93 330 335 333 312]

(sql: expected 2 arguments, got 25)
```

When I try hardcoding, I get the same issue:

```
db.Exec("UPDATE product_supplier SET deleted_at=? WHERE supplier_id = ? AND sku NOT IN (?)", time.Now(), 3, []int{313, 108})
```

Output:

```
(sql: expected 2 arguments, got 4)
```

**Solution:**

The code is not actually bugged at all. Was me being silly - I had an extra parameter in my actual code than I should have. I just didn't translate it for stack overflow correctly. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

The natural of `prepare` functionality prevents you from passing a slice as an argument.

The implementation of `db.Exec` in Go is to first `prepare` the query (including the variable placeholders) and then send the arguments.

If you wonder why `prepare` prevents you from passing a slice, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663243/2601733).

As a workaround, the same amount of placeholders as the size of your slice need to be concatenated in your program, which should be generating a query like this:

```
... WHERE supplier_id = ? AND sku NOT IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Example code:

```
Ids := []int{1, 2, 3}
query := "... WHERE supplier_id = ? AND sku NOT IN (" + genVar(len(Ids)) + ")"
db.Exec(query, 3, Ids)
```

**UPDATE:**

It turns `Gorm`'s implementation of `db.Exec` method is not using prepare functionality from DBMS, but it concatenate strings in the driver.

My diagnosis now is that there might be something wrong in the dependencies.

Are you importing `Gorm` like it shows in http://jinzhu.me/gorm/ ?

Comment: This is exactly the workaround that I already did (many thanks), however I thought that I may be doing something wrong given that the library shows quite clearly that it allows you to do `NOT IN (?)`.

Comment: Also, see their tests: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/021d7b33143de37b743d1cf660974e9c8d3f80ea/main_test.go#L481 and https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/021d7b33143de37b743d1cf660974e9c8d3f80ea/main_test.go#L449 as example usage

Comment: @Gravy Aha, I see. Are you sure that you are importing the library correctly? It seems to me that you are using the Go's official sql library but not the `gorm` one, they have the same method but different implementation.

Comment: In `gorm`'s source code (https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/5174cc5c242a728b435ea2be8a2f7f998e15429b/scope.go#L501), they have different implementation of the `db.Exec` method, which it didn't use prepare functionality to pre-analyze query on the database side, but it concatenates arguments in the code.

Comment: Problem solved. Was me being silly - I had an extra parameter in my actual code than I should have. Just didnt translate it for stack overflow correctly. My bad. Thanks for your help.